# Arduino Mega and Wifly shield

Tags: arduino, wifly, wifi, arduino

I bought a WiFly shield ( http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9367 ) for my Arduino Mega board and am trying to hook it up.

I tried the wireless talker tutorial which seem to be very popular http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorial_info.php?tutorials_id=158

I tried running the first sketch, but it doesn't work. It just gives me a Bridge Locked up message. I tried changing the pin associations in the code as discussed in this post http://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=22067&p=104343 
but again no joy.

I tried the standard WiFly library that sparkfun ship from here ( http://sparkfun.com/Code/wifly/WiFly-20100519-023939.zip )
I extracted the zip files, put them under the libraries directory of the IDE, fired up the IDE, started the example and tried to run it, again no go. I put my credentials in the credentials.h file, changed the pin associations in the Spi.h file (for CS, MOSI, MISO, SCK) as suggested above to 53,51,50,52 respectively. Again, no joy. The terminal window just sits there showing "WiFly Shield Terminal Routine".

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone used the WiFly module by itself or with the Arduino mega board? Do I need to hook up the Mega's 50 - 12 pins to the WiFly shield somehow? There seems to be a similar discussion here with no resolution http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1270926864

PS: I am running this on Windows 7, 64 bit

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i have the same problem as one mentioned above. exact problem indeed. same on other pages. no resolution for arduino mega boards.

Comment: Really? The link in the answer below worked for me for the Mega boards. Although, I had the old Mega board. I think sparkfun sell a different type of Mega these days I think. But have a closer look at the link below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, more information here ( http://mcukits.com/2009/04/06/arduino-ethernet-shield-mega-hack/ ). Even though this is for Ethernet, I have to do the same thing with the WiFly module and rewire the pins.